# Proving a formula for $\pi$

Tags: sequences-and-series, pi

I found a formula for $\pi$ in [this paper](https://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/0912/0912.0303.pdf). However, I could not find any proof of this formula, and I don't know how to approach to it. Is there good explanation for it?

$$ \pi + 3 = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n2^nn!^2}{(2n)!} $$

Comment: Ramanujan's work may interest you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's part of an exercise from the book *Pi and the AGM* by Borwein and
Borwein.

Prove that
$$\frac{2x\sin^{-1}x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}=\sum_{m=1}^\infty \frac{m!^2(2x)^{2m}}{m(2m)!}.\tag{1}$$
Hint: show that $f=(\sin^{-1}x)/\sqrt{1-x^2}$ satisfies
$(1-x^2)f'=1+xf$.

Granted $(1)$, differentiating and multiplying by $x$ gives
a formula for
$$\sum_{m=1}^\infty \frac{m!^2(2x)^{2m}}{(2m)!}.$$
Doing it again, gives a formula for
$$\sum_{m=1}^\infty m\frac{m!^2(2x)^{2m}}{(2m)!}.$$
Finally set $x=1$.

Comment: Nice proof! You might want to set $x = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$ instead at the end.

Comment: Really Thanks! I will try this.